# Несколько значений в условии

Tags: javascript, jquery, условия

Подскажите пожалуйста, как выполнить это условие в одну строку, чтобы оно также выполнялось, если v.color == 1, v.color == 2, v.color == 3 и т.д. Ставил знак ||, но что-то не получается.

```
if( v.base == 0 && v.model == 0 && v.filled == 1 && v.color == 1 ) sum = 24;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
var v = {
  base: 0,
  model: 0,
  filled: 1,
  color: 3
};

if (v.base === 0 &&
  v.model === 0 &&
  v.filled === 1 &&
  (v.color === 1 || v.color === 2 || v.color === 3)) {
  sum = 24;
}

// или, если вариантов значений много
var colors = [1, 2, 3, 100, 500];

if (v.base === 0 &&
  v.model === 0 &&
  v.filled === 1 &&
  colors.indexOf(v.color) !== -1) {
  sum = 24;
}
```